# Doctrine2 cascade default value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I'm actually learning Symfony3 and more precisely the Doctrine2 relation between objects and I was wondering if there is a default value for the cascade parameter when you don't explicite it.

I seen in tutorials when it's necessary to use the remove value that the parameter is not specified, but there is no explanation about this fact.

So I mean is this

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UTM\ForumBundle\Entity\UtmWebsiteTopics")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $topic;
```

equivalent to that ?

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UTM\ForumBundle\Entity\UtmWebsiteTopics", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $topic;
```

Thank you for reading and I hope you'll be able to bring me an answer. :D

Comment: Suppose that `cascade` has no default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, those two snippets are not the same. If you were to want to delete a specific entity that has relations to others through FK, you would need to explicitly `remove()` the related entities to avoid Integrity Constraint Violations.

Examples of each

**Not defining `cascade={"remove"}`**

```
public function removeEntityAction($id)
{
    // Get entity manager etc....
    $myEntity = $em->getRepository("MyEntity")->findBy(["id" => $id]);

    foreach($myEntity->getTopics() as $topic) {
        $em->remove($topic);
    }

    $em->remove($myEntity);
}
```

**Defining `cascade={"remove"}`**

```
public function removeEntityAction($id)
{
    // Get entity manager etc....
    $myEntity = $em->getRepository("MyEntity")->findBy(["id" => $id]);

    $em->remove($myEntity);
}
```

[Doctrine Cascade Operations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

[Doctrine - Removing Entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities)